# Negative binomial regression does not converge

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, convergence

I am trying to use a Negative Binomial regression model for some count data in which the dependent count variable takes on the values 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.  I am using SAS and keep running into the warning: "The relative Hessian convergence criterion of X is greater than the limit of 0.0001. The convergence is questionable." where X ranges approximately from 0.001 to 250.  I am just working with univariate models at this point, and this is an issue for all types of independent variables (e.g., whether the independent variable in the model is a continuous variable like age or a categorical variable like income level).

I also noticed that the estimate for dispersion is always 0 and followed by either 0's all across for standard error and 95% Wald CIs or by a standard error of <0.01 and missing values for the 95% Wald CIs.  The estimates and standard errors for the independent variables equal those if I run a Poisson regression rather than a negative binomial regression (I'm guessing because the dispersion estimate = 0).

Is there a way to fix the convergence issue?